# Making header tabs in wordpress smaller

Tags: wordpress

My header looks the following way: [image]

My categories are my header and I'd like to make them all fit on one line. I looked at the style.css file. However, I do not have web design experience and do not know what exactly to modify.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an excellent question, the answer is relatively simple.

1. Open Mozilla Firefox and go to your site
2. install the simple custom css plugin
3. go to your homepage and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
4. hover over the item in question and when it is highlighted, click on it
5. in the html console in the bottom you will see a line like this
6. right click the line and select "copy css selector"

Here is where it can get a little tricky, go to your Simple custom CSS under the appearance tab. Then enter paste-your-css-selector { width: ex 75px; height: ex 25px;}

Please post any questions you have in the comment section